# MSH could be different in batch HL7 file?

Tags: hl7

I am new to Health care domain's project. In this project I am having a batch HL7 file that contains multiple patient information in the below format.

```
FSH
MSH
PID
OBR
OBX
MSH
PID
OBR
OBX
OBX
```

SO my concern is that MSH segment can be a different in same batch file or it should be same.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The MSH header would typically be different betweeen the different records as each set of segments describes one complete transaction (with some execptions). In a batched layout, where the transmission may occur because of an accumulation of records over time that is sent out to the destination on some time interval, there would be several expected differences. If you consider the link below that describes the field layout for the MSH segment, I would at a minimum expect that the date time of message in the batch to differ based on when the actual event occurred and the message control id. 
  It would also be possible for the message type to differ depending on what your batch reflects. I included a link to the Texas immunization batch specification that expresses a uniqueness constraint on the MSH msg control id

http://www.corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources/hl7-msh-message-header

https://www.dshs.state.tx.us/immunize/docs/immtrac/HL7_Data_Transfer_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can have different MSH in a HL7 file containing batch results. I am developing HL7 interfaces since last 10 years. As message header can change for results it is possible to do so. You can have same MSH for all results or different MSH for every result in a batch file.